# Improve the UX of App's Back Navigation

Tags: navigation, ios, tab-bar

I have a tabbed style iOS application.

[image]

When they click, "Snap it" it directs them to a new screen from which they select a photo that the app takes and suggests possible species. At the same time, in the background the app adds this newly snapped leaf to the user's collection, which they can view by clicking "Browse".

Once the list of possible species is generated, the app then takes them to a new screen that shows the list. In the old version of the app, there was a back arrow that took the user to the screen showing their collection. However, I don't think that makes sense, since the last screen the view saw was the one in which they selected a photo.

**How can I improve the UX of this page so that the back arrow would suggest, "View leaf in my collection" (without adding that as text next to the back arrow of course). Is there standard navigation terminology for this?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **back** button should do just that: go back. Viewing in the collection is an entirely new action (unless you were just in the collection). Therefore, consider simply adding an action button to this UI.

*Please forgive the awful paintjob*

[image]

Comment: If the user can also their collection by clicking, "browse" (And then choosing "My collection" from the seg control which features 'App Database/My Collection') -- does it make sense/seem important for their to be a View in Collection button here?

Comment: If users frequently view their collection after taking a picture, yes. If not, no, it doesn't make sense. In either case the back button makes the least sense.